how to use "Cut particles to shape" to "trim a lawn" in areas defined by objects
My goal is to not have tall lawn grass (hair) not show through heavy objects on a lawn (like a chair leg or other object.   I would like to understand any way of using the ParticleEdit.shape_object and bpy.ops.particle.shape_cut() button:

For me, not matter the object (sphere, plane), all the hair particles disappear when I click on Cut button.
I can find no use cases in my search of this site and would like to discover any.
My example file: 
I also think that this question could be helped by an answer to this.

The Cut Particles to Shape operation  works the other way around than you expect.  It's like a Bowl Cut hairstyle: put a bowl over the head and cut off everything that is not covered by the bowl.
In your case, you place the sphere on the grass (particles) and everything outside the sphere is cut off:

It seems not to work with a plane as cut object. You need to extrude it to a box then it works as you expect.
If you want to cut off the grass under an object, I would use a vertex group for the Vertex Group > Density in the particle settings or an image texture as shown here: How to use a texture to affect particle density
